# BS4 при парсинге

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

В ходе работы возник вопрос.
На изображении ниже указана часть HTML кода, который нужно спарсить, достать данный текст не сложно, однако под данных тегом находятся другие, которые тоже содержат текст, который мне не нужен.
Мне нужно как-то достать только то, что находится под `::before` и
до  `<div class="row ravenol-item-description">`
https://podbor.ravenol.su/1-cars/1-abarth/6-124-spider-348/15236-124-spider-1-4-turbo-multi-air/  - сайт с которого собираю инфу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тоесть вам какой текст из того что есть на картинке получить нужно? И еще, не поленитесь дать ссылку на страницу которую пытаетесь парсить или приведите более полный пример интересующего вас тега в виде текста.

Comment: Добавил сайт и более детальную фотографию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверьте, Вы это имели ввиду?

```py
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

if __name__ == '__main__':
    response = requests.get('https://podbor.ravenol.su/'
                            '1-cars/1-abarth/6-124-spider-348/'
                            '15236-124-spider-1-4-turbo-multi-air/')

    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = Soup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        useful_tag = soup.find('div', class_='panel-body')
        while useful_tag.div:
            useful_tag.div.replace_with('')
        text_blocks = [text.strip() for text in re.findall(r'[^\n\t]+', useful_tag.text) if text.strip()]
        print(text_blocks)
# ['Объем жидкости (основной): 3.8  л', 'Объем жидкости (фильтр): 0.6  л', 'Режим эксплуатации: нормальный', 'Проверка, км: 3000', 'Замена каждые 15000 км или 12 мес.']
```

Comment: Да!
Спасибо вам большое!